# Change elements container without changing elements position

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I drag element from one container to second container (containers are independent).
On drag starting I add dragged element to the body (this is necessary).
If I drop element to the second container I get element coordinates relative to the body instead of second container so my element appears in wrong location in second container

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include more relevant information. Is the draggable element perhaps position:absolute? In that case, make sure to give it's containers position:relative so it snaps to it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

Html looks something like this:

```
<div id="designer">  
   <div class="ui-layout-center">
     <div id="workspace"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="ui-layout-north">
     content
   </div>

   <div class="ui-layout-west">
     <div class="elements">
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#workspace {
   position:relative;
}
.work-element { /*class for dropped element*/
  position:absolute;
}
```

JS

```
$('.elements .element').draggable({
    helper: copyElementHelper
});

$("#workspace").droppable({
    accept: '.element',
    drop: onWorkspaceDrop
});

function copyElementHelper(event) {
    var $element = $('<div></div>');

    return $element.appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 5).show();
};

function onWorkspaceDrop(event, ui) {
    // logic for adding element to workspace
    // create element
    // add class work-element to created element
    // set positions for created element using ui param
    // here I have position relative to body
    // how to transform it to be position relative to workspace
};
```